# Topic created in all kafka port

Tags: java, apache-kafka

server.propereties setup:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:29092, SSL://:29093
```

SSL related set too done.

so that we can connect 29092 for plaintext and 29093 along with SSL setup.

Here am trying to produce data into port 29093 as below

```
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, System.getProperty("kafkaPort", "localhost:29093"));

//SSL related setup too done in props

Producer<Long, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props, new LongSerializer(), new KafkaSerializer());

final ProducerRecord<Long, String> record = new ProducerRecord<Long, String>(System.getProperty("kafkaTopic", "dqerror"),
                    content);

RecordMetadata metadata = producer.send(record).get();
```

After publishing dqerror topic created in both also data get published in both
Data is published into two topic.

Actually, am trying to find is any possible to restrict to drop data into a specific port ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is not published in "both" ports. There is only one Kafka cluster that is listening on two ports. There is one set of disks that the data is written into on your one broker.

Also, from what I can tell, there is only **one** topic used in your code.

If you want to restrict TCP traffic on any port, that would be a firewall rule from the OS, rather than any Kafka settings or Java code.

Comment: Thanks much for your response and suggestion, Yes the server has a single data for each publish. From the viewing tool, I get confused and I thought data get duplicated.